# Stable Diffusion issue on intel mac: connecting the weights/model and connecting to the model.ckpt file

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to get a command line version of Stable Diffusion up and running on Mac Intel from the following repo: https://github.com/cruller0704/stable-diffusion-intel-mac

I'm getting the error:
`Too many levels of symbolic links: 'models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/model.ckpt'` I don't 100% know what it means (I mean I kind of do but not really), or how to fix it.

I created and activated a conda environment with:

```
conda env create -f environment.yaml
conda activate ldm
```

I then did this:

```
mkdir -p models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/
ln -s <path/to/model.ckpt> models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/model.ckpt
```

I didn't do anything with the following and I guess this is the problem as the above maybe needs to link to this, but renamed? https://github.com/cruller0704/stable-diffusion-intel-mac#weights I don't know what to do with this, what do I do? It talks about these being weights, but are these the model or just the weights? and... what do I do with them? I clicked through some links there and couldn't figure out how to download anything. Any suggestions what to do next?  Thank you!

**edit: ok that link says: `We currently provide the following checkpoints:` So, it's not just the weights it's the model in it's current state as well I guess.  But how do I get them? They're not in the downloaded zip.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first models are provided by Stability AI, their source is their website hugging face.  Higher model numbers are more popular but there are other reasons to run lower versioned files.

https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5
Lower in the page you can find.
https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5/resolve/main/v1-5-pruned-emaonly.ckpt

This is SD 1.5 model for example.  Googling "stable diffusion 1.5 model download" and modifying it for the version you're looking for and grabbing it from hugging face is the source you're looking for.